# Event to notify while getting call

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any events in Windowsphone 8 to notify my application while the phone getting a call?

So that the application can make actions at that time.

Answer (score 0):

No. When the user takes a phone call, you will get `Application Deactivated` (but this event is raised in other cases to). These event is designed to quickly save the app state for resume, nothing else, there are limitations (e.g. 10 seconds running time).

Comment: That is true for *WP8.0* and *WP8.1 Silverlight*, in *WP8.1 Runtime* there are *Suspending/Resuming* events.